# JSONP Callback not working for Beats Music API

Tags: api, jsonp, beatsmusic

I'm trying to use the API via JSONP - making a request like:

https://partner.api.beatsmusic.com/v1/api/search/federated?callback=beatsCallback&q=cats&client_id=XXXXX

But the response just comes back as pure json - not wrapped in a callback.  Are callbacks supported?

Answer (score 1):

Beats Music supports CORS which allows javascript on a page to make requests to another domain, not the domain it originated from. Thus, you do not need to use JSONP and can access the json in a traditional manner.